# jQuery Mobile native application form post to another page

Tags: php, mysql, css, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to build a native mobile application using jQuery Mobile and then wrapping it in PhoneGap. This is my first attempt at building a mobile application and I am kind of lost on a normally simple topic. My application will allow users to browse scores, schedules, and statistics for high school football teams. I have a page that shows all teams in a drop-down list (#search-schedules). A user will select a team, the team id value gets posted and the schedule for that team is shown on another page (#schedules). I include a custome.js file that has all of the jQuery that I need for the entire application. What I have so far (dealing with this question) is below. Any direction on the best way to achieve this is greatly appreciated.

This is the page where the user selects a team:

```
<div data-role="page" id="search-schedules">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Find Schedules</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p align="center"><strong>Select a school from the list below to view their schedule</strong></p>
        <form id="schedules-form" data-transition="pop" data-direction="reverse" />
            <div align="center" data-role="fieldcontain">
                <select name="school" id="school-select">
                    <option value="">Select A School</option>
                </select>
                <p><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Get Schedule" data-theme="b" /></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-dividertheme="e">
        <li><a href="#home" data-transition="slide">Home Page</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div data-role="footer"><h1>Footer</h1></div>
</div>
```

This is the page where the schedule will be displayed:

```
<div data-role="page" id="schedules">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Schedules</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <h2 align="center"></h2>
        <div id="schedule-div"></div>
    </div>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-dividertheme="e">
        <li><a href="index.php" data-transition="slide">Home Page</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div data-role="footer"><h1>Footer</h1></div>
</div>
```

This is the JS that submits the form:

```
$('#schedules-form').bind('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(serviceURL + 'schedules.php', $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
        $.mobile.changePage('#schedules', {
            transition: 'slide'
        });
    });
});
```

This is the JS that displays the schedule:

```
$('#schedules').live('pageshow', function(event) {
    var team = ''; // How do I grab a POST variable?
    $.post(serviceURL + 'schedules.php', team, function(data) {
        var games = data.item;
        $.each(games, function(index, game) {
            $('#schedule-div').append('<p>' + game.game_date + ' - ' + game.visitor_team + ' @ ' + game.home_team + '</p>');
        });
        $('#schedule-div').listview('refresh');
    });
};
```

Comment: I've just started diving into jQuery mobile, but doesn't it, in most usages, not technically change your current page at all? Even if your loading the sub pages with ajax, your still on the same page and it's just fading them in on a new div. If that is the case, why not just pass the data attribute needed using a data tag to the ajax function loading the teams schedule?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, jQuery mobile doesn't actually change your current page, it just loads subsequent pages into the DOM. Have your team links fire the page transition and pass the id needed to retrieve the teams schedule with a 'data-teamId' attribute. Use one of the jQuery mobile events like 'pageload' (i haven't looked too much into the exact moments the events are fired yet) to start loading your team schedule via ajax with the data attribute you grabbed on the link click. On complete, display the schedule.

Comment: I could be wrong though, I've only used jQuery mobile enough to lift and modify some of their touch functions and looked around the documentation a bit lol, but you should be able to script the ajax loading using the events that are fired when a page is loaded and moved into the viewing area.